# How to use forward_list::remove_if for removing callbacks

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm trying to implement an `Event` class in C++11. Adding event handlers and triggering the event works great but I have trouble removing handlers from the event. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename... Values>
class Event
{

public:
    typedef void(Signature)(Values...);
    typedef std::function<Signature> Handler;

public:

    void operator () (Values... values) {
        for (const auto& handler: handlers) {
            handler(values...);
        }
    }

    Event& operator += (const Handler& handler) {
        handlers.push_front(handler);
        return *this;
    }

    Event& operator -= (const Handler& handler) {
        handlers.remove_if([&](const Handler& entry) {
            return entry.template target<Signature>() == handler.template target<Signature>();
        });
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::forward_list<Handler> handlers;
};

void handler1(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << "Event handler 1 " << std::endl;
}

void handler2(int i, int a) {
    std::cout << "Event handler 2 " << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {
  Event<int, int> event;

  // Add two event handlers
  event += handler1;
  event += handler2;

  // Both event handlers should be called (Works)
  event(1, 2);

  // Remove one of the event handlers
  event -= handler2;

  // The other one should still be called (Fails!)
  event(1, 2);
}
```

My problem is that the subtraction operator always removes ALL event handlers, not just the specified one. I'm pretty sure the condition I use for the `remove_if` method is wrong, but I don't see the problem. When I debug the code then this condition is always `true` which is not what I need. Can someone please help?

Comment: The immediate problem is that your type is incorrect. It should be `Signature*` or something similar. But that doesn't solve the underlying problem.

Comment: For example, you can add `Handler`s that do not refer to `void(int, int)` functions. Those cannot be removed using your `operator -=`.

Comment: The second immediate problem is that `target` *returns a pointer to the stored function (object)*. In your case, that's a *pointer to a function pointer*. Those pointers will of course be different, you had to dereference the pointer to compare the function pointers.

Comment: `boost::signals2` solves this problem by returning a handle object that can be used to remove the Handler: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#idp204831192

Comment: Stra,ge when I print the return value of target type I always get `nullptr`....

Comment: @Johan Because it's the wrong type, as I said. Try `target<Signature*>`

Comment: @Johan Yes, the pointers are indeed NULL. So that's why the condition is always true.

Comment: @dyp: When I use `target<Signature*>` in the condition then the pointers are always different. So it now always returns false. EDIT: Ah, sorry, you already said I have to dereference the pointers. Looks like it is working then.

Comment: @kayahr: Make sure you only dereference the pointer when it is non-null! Although you currently only add function pointers, any function object with a suitable signature can be added and the returned pointer will be null.

Comment: @Dietmar Yes, you are right. When I store a lambda in a variable and add this one to the event then the code segfaults on removal. The null check fixes this crash but actually it would be nice if I could remove these type of event handlers, too. Maybe I should ditch this idea and do it more like boost as suggested by dyp. This pointer magic gets too complicated.

Comment: @kayahr: Lambdas are not equality comparable. It is possible to create something like `std::function<..>` which supports equality comparison for instances which are equality comparable but using s key obtained at tegistration point works for all function object types.